# Maven Duplicate plugin realm for plugin

Tags: maven, jenkins, soapui

We have a project where we use Maven 3.0.5 to build it. Besides that we use eviware:maven-soapui-plugin:4.5.1 plugin with couple of executions in pre-integration-test and integration-test phases. These test phases are used in couple of sub modules where two modules pass the tests and third module fails on the error bellow.

We have moved from Maven 2.2.1 to 3.0.5. On our local machine everything builds fine.
On our build machine using Jenkins we get the following error:

```
message : Internal error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate plugin realm for plugin eviware:maven-soapui-plugin:4.5.1
cause : Duplicate plugin realm for plugin eviware:maven-soapui-plugin:4.5.1
Stack trace : 
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate plugin realm for plugin eviware:maven-soapui-plugin:4.5.1
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.BuilderCommon.handleBuildError(BuilderCommon.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:95)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:158)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:100)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:66)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate plugin realm for plugin eviware:maven-soapui-plugin:4.5.1
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginRealmCache.put(DefaultPluginRealmCache.java:170)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.setupPluginRealm(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:323)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getPluginRealm(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:78)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    ... 24 more
```

Using Maven 2.2.1 everything was working fine on both local as Jenkins enviroments.

Any clue what "Duplicate plugin realm for plugin" is and how to fix this?

Cheers,

Tuno

Comment: Interesting problem. The error happens when two plugins are registered in the session, but looking at maven's source code (class [DefaultMavenPluginManager.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.maven/maven-core/3.0.5/org/apache/maven/plugin/internal/DefaultMavenPluginManager.java?av=f) ) this shouldn't happen as the method `setupPluginRealm` is synchronized and first checks the cache and after that it updates it if it cannot find the key.

Comment: Not a solution, but more a workaround. After adding a new "Build a free-style software project" job and some manual customizations, it worked. Not ideal. It's strange why this is working differently. Maybe something in Jenkins or the environment Jenkins is running on.